# How to run CLI migrations in a Continous Integration pipeline on a private database on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-rds, database-migration, prisma

I am currently using a tool that allows you to apply database migrations only using a CLI ([Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)). My database is in a private network in AWS.

To do it manually, I currently do this:

```
ssh -i $SSH_PATH_TO__MY_IDENTITY_FILE ec2-user@${BASTION_HOSTNAME} \
    -N -f -L $DB_PORT:${DB_HOSTNAME}:5432 &
```

A bastion, in AWS parlance, is just a VM that has public access but also can reach private networks. This `ssh` command creates a tunnel through the bastion so that I can reach the private machine in my local `$DB_PORT`. Then, I apply the migrations locally but, since the database is listening on a local port, I can reach my production database.

Here is the question: how do I move this to a CI/CD pipeline?

I was thinking about doing this

1. Use a docker image that has `ssh` and `nodejs` installed,
2. Move the identity file to a env variable in the CI/CD.
3. Install the migrations tool there.
4. Create a tunnel as I did above.
5. Modify the configuration file to point to the production database.

And then, finally, apply the migrations.

I think this could work, but it seems a lot of trouble and I was wondering that maybe there was a better, standard way to approach this. Maybe triggering a Lambda function that runs inside the private network?

Comment: Which CI/CD tool are you using specifically? And is that tool running on AWS? For example AWS CodePipeline/CodeBuild can run inside the same VPC as your RDS instance in order to connect to the database just like your bastion host.

Comment: @MarkB I'm using GitLab CI, but I am willing to switch if I find a better alternative. I'll check CodeBuild out. Thanks!

Comment: You could trigger a CodeBuild step from GitLab CI. Or you could use a GitLab CI runner inside the VPC. I have also seen Lambda used for migrations, as well as ECS Fargate tasks (for long running migrations).

Comment: did you ever find a way to achieve this? any decent company out there will be running their prod db behind a VPC, having to interact with the database during CI is a real productivity killer

Comment: Yeah, I found a way to do it. I followed the recommendations and triggered a Lamda function from the CI. Then, I switched to a Kubernetes job because it was easier to set up in an automated way.